# How to perform a click on a href with javascript function with nightmare

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, href, nightmare

I wanted to know how can i click a button with nightmare with this attributes .

```
<a class="auth_button leftbtn" href="javascript:SubmitAuthCode( 'enter a friendly name here' );">
        <h3>Submit</h3>
        <h5>my special access code</h5>
</a>
```

I tried to use the click() method like this :

```
 .click('.auth_button leftbtn');
```

But it just doesn't click it( Probably because its not a "real" button - might be wrong)

 Any ideas why?Or how should i do it instead

I may found out why the .click() doesn't work:

```
<div class="modal_buttons" id="auth_buttonsets">
    <div class="auth_buttonset" id="auth_buttonset_entercode" style="display: none;">
            <a class="auth_button leftbtn" href="javascript:SubmitAuthCode( 'enter a friendly name here' );">
                <h3>Submit</h3>
                <h5>my special access code</h5>
            </a>
            <a class="auth_button" href="javascript:SetEmailAuthModalState( 'checkspam' );">
                <h3>What message?</h3>
                <h5>I don't have any message from Steam Support...</h5>
            </a>
            <div style="clear: left;"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="auth_buttonset" id="auth_buttonset_checkspam" style="display: none;">
            <a class="auth_button leftbtn" href="javascript:SubmitAuthCode( 'enter a friendly name here' );">
                <h3>Found it!</h3>
                <h5>and I've entered my special access code above</h5>
            </a>
            <a class="auth_button" href="javascript:SetEmailAuthModalState( 'help' );">
                <h3>No luck still...</h3>
                <h5>I don't have any message from Steam Support...</h5>
            </a>
            <div style="clear: left;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The button i'm aiming at is in the the div `id=auth_buttonset_entercode`because there are multiple buttons with the same id , but not in the same div . Now i dont know how to select the div and then the class at the same selector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change it to

```
.click('#auth_buttonset_entercode .auth_button.leftbtn');
```

So it will select the element with *both classes*.

Comment: Will try when I get home , seems promising